# Visual Studio: Building a partial solution by both GUI and Command Line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm working on a megaproject.  There are a number of drop-in components all built in the same solution file.  Each component has a post-build event to copy itself to the executable's bin folder so it can be dynamically loaded by the executable.

I can create a configuration in the GUI that only builds the projects I care about and this works great in the GUI, on my PC.  All the components build, and copy themselves to the right folder.  ...but it doesn't transfer to other PCs and doesn't transfer to the command line, where all components are building.  (Is the enabled/disabled status stored in .suo instead of .sln?)

```
MSBuild "MegaSolution.sln" /p:Configuration="Limited Release"
```

I can build from the command line one .csproj file at a time if I remove the post-build command and specify OutDir, OutputPath, and SolutionDir on the command line...

```
MSBuild "MyComponent.csproj" /t:Build  /p:Configuration="Limited Release";OutDir="..\..\%outdir%";OutputPath="..\..\%outdir%";SolutionDir="..\.."
```

... but then the GUI build is broken because of missing xcopies.

I then tried creating a whole new solution file.  Putting my project specific solution file in the project folder caused further issues with relative paths in the post build commands, so I put the solution at the same level as the primary solution, which works great in the GUI output, but with the console the projects are outputting to the wrong folder:

From GUI build output window:

```
Architecture -> C:\...\Architecture\bin\Release\Architecture.dll
Launcher -> C:\...\Launcher\bin\Release\TestApp.exe
```

From Command Line:

```
MSBuild "MyProjectStandalone.sln" /p:Configuration="Release"
Architecture -> C:\...\Architecture\Launcher\bin\Release\Architecture.dll
Launcher -> C:\...\Launcher\Launcher\bin\Release\TestApp.exe
```

I can find no explination for this behavior after searching for "Launcher" in all files in the solution folder.

I tried replacing the xcopies with output paths, but you can't use the SolutionDir or Configuration variables in OutputPath to edit both configurations at once, they are used as plain text.

```
C:\...\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2019-00D7

 Directory of ...\bin

03/24/2015  08:52 PM    <DIR>          .
03/24/2015  08:52 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/24/2015  08:52 PM    <DIR>          $(Configuration)
03/24/2015  08:49 PM    <DIR>          Debug
03/24/2015  08:52 PM    <DIR>          Release
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           5 Dir(s)  101,571,932,160 bytes free
```

I tried hard coding the OutDir in each project/configuration to replace the xcopy, then hard coding the OutDir in the msbuild call to the solution. The outputfolder is relative to the project being built, not the solution folder, so with the command below, one dependancy tree is going to `..\..\output`, while the other is going to `..\..\..\output`

```
MSBuild "MyProjectStandalone.sln" /p:Configuration="Release";OutDir="..\..\..\..\output"
```

I am able to get it to work by removing all the xcopies, and compiling each project seprately with hard coded OutDir that relative to that project, but I'd like this to work with the solution file.

Comment: Additional note, every dependency of the project you build will use the relative path from it's own project folder.  The intended output will end up with all the needed files, but there will be build artifacts left in untidy places.  I ended up changing my output directory in my batch script to an absolute path:  SET outputDir=%~dp0..\..\output

Comment: I think you need to open up and play around with your .csproj files. Add things like `<Message Text="foo=$(foo)" Importance="high">` to them to debug why your outputs are going where they are. You can indeed use `$(SolutionDir)` in your OutDir/OutputPath, but Visual Studio tends to escape the characters -- you need to use `$(SolutionDir)` in your .csproj files instead (don't worry - VS renders it nicely and won't revert). Lastly, I recommend against using xcopy for copying outputs unless you really need two copies. Otherwise, as you did already, OutDir is the way to go.

Comment: Ah, if I put $(SolutionDir)\Launcher\bin\Release\ in the project file it works, but in the GUI it mangles it.  Need to test that with MSBuild...